# entry function for python sort function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, search

I'm trying to make an small terminal search engine (python 3.9, VS Code) and I wrote this function as the key function for sort. When I don't write the list parameter, `list.index` is meaningless and when I write it, it returns an error, could you check it out?

```
def soort(self, keyword):
    return self.index(keyword)
list_high = []
listname = ['breaking bad', 'dark', 'stranger things',
             'vikings', 'game of thrones', 'prison break',
             'sherlock', 'silicon valley', 'lost', 'friends']
search = 'br'
for name in listname:
    if search in name:
        list_high.append(name)
list_high.sort(key=soort(list_high, search))
print(list_high)
```

Comment: have a better look at how to write the `key` argument of the sort method, also the use of `self` is confusing

Comment: there's no rule for that. self made sense to me in that situation.

Comment: if you are writing an entry for the Python Obfuscation Contest keep on going but if you need this code reviewed before committing it does not adhere to readable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_high.sort(key=soort(list_high, search))
```

This calls `soort(list_high, search)` once then passes its return value (an integer) as the `key` argument for `sort`, which makes no sense (integers are not callable).

You need to make sure to pass in a callable.

You should also consider using `.find` instead of `.index`, as `.index` will raise a `ValueError` if it can't find the searched string. `.find` will return `-1`.

```
list_high.sort(key=lambda word: word.find('br'))
```